# Module "CocoaLumberjackSwift" not found in latest wikipedia-ios app on XCode 9

Tags: ios, xcode, wiki

I am using wikipedia-ios app for educational purposes, and I successfully used XCode 8 with it. But after the update I get the following error on trying to build the app:

Module "CocoaLumberjackSwift" not found
File: WMFLogging.h

I have used the scripts/setup from wiki's archive, and also I have cleaned the build (and all of the derived data). I even removed the project entirely and download it anew. Still I get the same error. Could someone please help me out with it?

Comment: Have you tried removing the pod and installing it again ?

Comment: How can I remove the pod? I have removed the whole directory and downloaded it anew, but that did not help.

Comment: in your pod file remove the line : pod 'CocoaLumberjack' , then save the file, go to command line and type in pod install, that will remove your pod. Try installing it again see if it works. Hope this helps